# How to create chart in google sheets with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using javascript to create Google-sheets-document with user data. The document is saved on the user's Drive.
I can't figure out how to make a graph from the data i have inserted. I am using vanilla javascript with the Google sheets API.
It would probably look something like this:

```
  function createGraph() {
  
    gapi.client.sheets.graph
      .create({
        properties: {
          type(?): 'Pie'
          spreadsheetid: //some id
          range: 'A1:A10'
        },
      })
  }
```

EDIT: To specify, i want to insert the graph to the sheets-document that i have created, not to the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the chart to your spreadsheet, you can use Sheets API's [AddChartRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddChartRequest), as part of the [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) method.

#### Code snippet:

On broad terms, your request would look like this (check the reference below in order to build the request body in detail):

```
const payload = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "addChart": {
                "chart": {
                    "spec": { // Chart type, range source, etc.
                        "pieChart": { // Pie chart specification
                          // object (PieChartSpec)
                        }
                        // rest of ChartSpec properties
                    },
                    "position": { // Where the chart will be located
                        // object (EmbeddedObjectPosition)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]    
}

const params = {
    spreadsheetId = "YOUR-SPREADSHEET-ID",
    body = payload
}
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(params);
```

#### Render chart in browsers and mobile devices:

In case you just wanted to render the chart in a browser, but not add it to your spreadsheet, you would use [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart) (see [Visualization: Pie Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart), for example).

#### Reference:

- [Sheets API > Charts](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts)
- [EmbeddedChart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#EmbeddedChart)
- [ChartSpec](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#chartspec)
- [EmbeddedObjectPosition](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#EmbeddedObjectPosition)
- [PieChartSpec](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#PieChartSpec)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this example

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var data;
      var chart;

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {
        // Create our data table.
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn("string", "Topping");
        data.addColumn("number", "Slices");
        data.addRows([
          ["Mushrooms", 3],
          ["Onions", 1],
          ["Olives", 1],
          ["Zucchini", 1],
          ["Pepperoni", 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
          title: "How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night",
          width: 400,
          height: 300
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
          document.getElementById("chart_div")
        );
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400; height: 300;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Referred from
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Thanks for the help! This worked for me.

```
    function createGraphv2(spreadsheetIdGraph, endIndex) {
  var params = {
    // The spreadsheet to apply the updates to.
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetIdGraph, // TODO: Update placeholder value.
  };

  var batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequestBody = {
    // A list of updates to apply to the spreadsheet.
    // Requests will be applied in the order they are specified.
    // If any request is not valid, no requests will be applied.
    
        requests: [
          {
            addChart: {
              chart: {
                spec: {
                  title: 'Rapport',
                  basicChart: {
                    chartType: 'COLUMN',
                    legendPosition: 'BOTTOM_LEGEND',
                    axis: [
                      //X-AXIS
                      {
                        position: "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                        title: "FORBRUK"
                      },
                      //Y-AXIS
                      {
                        position: "LEFT_AXIS",
                        title: "TID"
                      }

                    ],

                    series: [
                      {
                        series: {
                          sourceRange: {
                            sources: [
                              {
                                sheetId: 0,
                                startRowIndex: 0,
                                endRowIndex: endIndex,
                                startColumnIndex: 5,
                                endColumnIndex: 6,
                              },
                            ],
                          },
                          
                        },
                        targetAxis: "LEFT_AXIS"
                      }
                    ]

                  }
                },
                position : {
                  newSheet : 'True'
                }
              },
             
            }
          }
        ],


    // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
  };

  var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
    params,
    batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequestBody
  );
  request.then(
    function (response) {
      // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
      console.log(response.result);
    },
    function (reason) {
      console.error("error: " + reason.result.error.message);
    }
  );
}
```